# Microsoft Teams: "Something went wrong" while installing my custom app into my organization's team

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I have created an app for Microsoft Teams that one can add to a team. The app is a chatbot created with the Microsoft Bot framework. I have already made two other apps with similar functionality that can be installed fine.

When I create my app using the App Studio (and link to an existing bot), everything is fine but when I try to add that to a team I get the "something went wrong" message and no request is sent to my bot either...

Has anyone faced a similar issue or does someone know how to debug this? My manifest is below.

The manifest is below (with ids replaced).

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "id": "my-id-is-here",
    "packageName": "nl.getsofia.teams.acceptance",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Sofia Melius B.V.",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.getsofia.nl",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.getsofia.nl/",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.getsofia.nl/"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Sofia Acceptance 2",
        "full": "Sofia Acceptance Nice"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "ACCEPTANCE bot",
        "full": "ACCEPTANCE bot long description"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "my-bot-id-is-here",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team"
            ],
            "commandLists": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "personal"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "Add user",
                            "description": "A manager can add a user"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Get overview",
                            "description": "Get an overview of registered hours"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Projects",
                            "description": "Manage all projects"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Register hours",
                            "description": "Register your hours"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Settings",
                            "description": "Set hour registration reminder times"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "*.sofiamelius.nl",
        "*.getsofia.nl"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am able to upload the shared manifest with my bot Id. Could you please share your bot id.

Comment: Are you getting this message when you try to add the bot to teams? If so, can you confirm that you actually activated the Teams channel for the bot? I got the same or similar message after I had done this a few times and then forgot that I had to turn the channel on in the Bot Service first.

Comment: @billoverton OMG yes that was it... can't believe I forgot to do that, thanks so much
if you upload that as answer, i can select it for others to see :)

Comment: I only know because I did it myself :) Would be nice if the Teams error message could actually tell you that!

Comment: The error messages when you fail to install a Teams app are really bad.  It's frustrating when you know that there is a whole message or at least an error code that could pinpoint the problem.  Even if you don't show it all by default, being able to open up the details would be a great help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this is occurring when you are attempting to deploy the bot to Teams (as opposed to trying to talk to it in Teams), the "Sorry, something went wrong" message is usually caused by the Teams channel in the Bot Service not being set up. You must both set up the manifest *and* turn on the channel.

To turn on the channel, just navigate to your Bot Service in the Azure Portal, select the Channels blade, and then click on Teams to save and activate the channel (I can't remember but I don't think you have to configure any settings here).

After that is complete, you should be able to publish your bot to Teams using any available method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to test with "Test team" team, which is apparently a special undeletable team that somehow exists in our teams.

Solution: Create a new Team and use your bot there.

Answer (score 0):

A general hint for everyone having problems uploading their app package to teams. Microsoft provides a tool to validate your created app package

- https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/appvalidation.html

I personally found this tool very helpful in order to create a vaild manifest.json file.