# Install bot using App Studio on Teams-error when installing bot using app studio

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I have created a bot package to install on Microsoft teams and i checked it using teams app validator and it passed all tests
[image]

but when i trying to install it on teams it give an error
[image]
what should i do to know what is the error?
the manifest version is 1.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Teams: "Something went wrong" while installing my custom app into my organization's team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059481/microsoft-teams-something-went-wrong-while-installing-my-custom-app-into-my-o)

Comment: Usually this is a case of not having the channel turned on in bot service. Please check details in linked question.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end could you please share your manifest?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT the problem was that i wasn't adding commands in the "commandLists" in the "bot" array  and parameters and parameters in the commands array in the "composeExtensions" array although the validator passed and didn't say any error

Comment: Could you please share your manifest?

Comment: @ShereenFathy -please share your manifest for further investigation?