# Teams custom app apears only sometimes on store after publishing it

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension, teams-toolkit

I have implemented a Message Extension using Teams Toolkit on VSCode.

After deploying on Azure & publishing on Microsoft Teams for the organization, Im only able to see the app sometimes inside the app store. That means the app is sometimes visible/available there and sometimes not visible/available.

So when it is visible and I try to install it, MS teams says "something went wrong".
After I try to add the app again it says nothing and opens the app.

I deployed and published the App yesterday.
Anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Teams: "Something went wrong" while installing my custom app into my organization's team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059481/microsoft-teams-something-went-wrong-while-installing-my-custom-app-into-my-o)

Comment: [Custom app installation fails with "Something went wrong"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/3178)

Comment: Usually Team Toolkit is using different Manifest-Version & Schema as default. 
Had to adjust them. Now it works fine!